# How to build an object representation in Javascript for the Honda Car models with their functions

Tags: javascript, oop, object

1. Honda Prelude (functionality : fourWheels(), stickGear() )
2. Honda NSX (functionality : fourWheels(), leatherSeat(), stickGear() )
3. Honda Accord (functionality : fourWheels(), leatherSeat() )

Comment: Are fourWheels functions or attributes - the syntax you've used looks like functions but logically they should probably be attributes

Comment: That would be the object property. A function

Comment: Well for a good object oriented design, you should define a class `Honda` that has only the property `fourWheels`, and then define another class `HondaPrelude` that extends the Honda class and `HondaAccord` class that extends Honda class and finally the `HondaNSX` class that extends one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes and inheritance:

```js
class HondaCar {
  fourWheels() {
    // method implementation
  }
}

class Prelude extends HondaCar {
  // override
  fourWheels() {
    // overridden method implementation
  }
  stickGear() {
    // method implementation
  }
}

class NSX extends Prelude {
  // override
  fourWheels() {
    // overridden method implementation
  }
  // override
  stickGear() {
    // overridden method implementation
  }
  leatherSeat() {
    // method implementation
  }
}

class Accord extends HondaCar {
  // override
  fourWheels() {
    // overridden method implementation
  }
  leatherSeat() {
    // method implementation
  }
}
```

Once you instantiate one of your child classes you get all the methods you have inherited from parent. The instance itself is the object representation of the car.

Comment: Note that `NSX` should extend the `Prelude` class or the `Accord` class and not `HondaCar` class

Comment: Thanks but I see the functions will be part of class instance. Sure I can override it but what if I don't need to.

Comment: Overriding functions (methods) is optional. I was just showing you an example that you can override the function/method implementation if you want. Since you are already inheriting ``HondaCar`` class, the parent class method will be available to the instance of child.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin's answer is good - here's a simpler one that is more generic and doesn't require inheritance - I'd only use something like this as a point solution though:

```
function car(name, hasFourWheels, hasStickGear, hasLeatherSeat ) {
    this.name = name;

    if(hasFourWheels == true){
      this.fourWheels = function fourWheels(){console.log("doing the four wheels function")}
    }
    
    if(hasStickGear == true){
        this.stickGear = function hasStickGear(){console.log("doing the stick gear function")}
    }
    
    if(hasLeatherSeat == true){
        this.leatherSeat = function hasLeatherSeat(){console.log("doing the leather seat function")}
    }
}


let car1 = new car("Honda Prelude", true, true, false);
let car2 = new car("Honda NSX", true, true, true);
let car3 = new car("Honda Accord", true, false, true);

//example usage
car2.stickGear();
```